# ASP.NET Core React Template with MVC Controllers & Views in same project

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Started with the ASP.Net Core with React (v6.0) template and am trying to add MVC Controllers & Views.

Have Added services.AddControllersWithViews() in ConfigureServices and the following is my Configure code:

```
 if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                // Catchall Route for our API Controllers
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
                                
            });            

            app.Run();
```

I can call API Controllers (i.e. weatherforecast and sample api) but when I add HomeController and then add /Views/Home/Index.cshtml I can never get it to route to the razor page - only api calls work.

I cannot find an example that shows both MVC Views and React Spa running in same solution.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

OK folks... the key here is to simply include the MVC routes in teh setupProxy.js